# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "a": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I want to swap position in a gridview and getting the syntax error on android.

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "a": syntax error (code 1):

```
 public void swapNewspaperSeialByPosition(int oldPosition, int newPosition) {

String selectQuery2 = "UPDATE " + TBL_NEWSPAPER + " a INNER JOIN " + TBL_NEWSPAPER
        + " b ON a.rowid <> b.rowid SET a.serialNo = b.serialNo WHERE a.rowid IN ("
        + oldPosition + "," + newPosition + ") AND b.rowid IN ("
        + newPosition + "," + oldPosition + ")";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL(selectQuery2);

}
```

The logcat here:

```
09-28 16:55:28.332: E/SQLiteLog(3047): (1) near "a": syntax error
09-28 16:55:28.332: E/InputEventReceiver(3047): Exception dispatching input event.
09-28 16:55:28.342: D/AndroidRuntime(3047): Shutting down VM
09-28 16:55:28.342: W/dalvikvm(3047): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4184e438)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "a": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE tbl_newspaper a INNER JOIN tbl_newspaper b ON a.rowid <> b.rowid SET a.serialNo = b.serialNo WHERE a.rowid IN (4,2) AND b.rowid IN (2,4)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at com.bangla.joyanews.DatabaseHelper.swapNewspaperSeialByPosition(DatabaseHelper.java:582)
09-28 16:55:28.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at FragmentAllNewspaper.swapNewspaperSeialByPosition(FragmentAllNewspaper.java:163)
```

Comment: Throw up your stacktrace, please.

Comment: @SBerg413 Logcat is provided.

Comment: Are you joining same table here?

Comment: @Rustam I just need to swap "Serial Number" of the same table just in different rows.